# Script creating a redirect warning

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I am working on my first site using google scripts.  I have a script embedded that creates a UI and references a Google spreadsheet to link to pages of the same site.  Whenever a link is clicked I get an interim page that says:

> The previous page is sending you to
>   https://sites.google.com/site/gchromeat/xxxx.
>
> If you do not want to visit that page, you can return to the previous
>   page.

Is there a way to get around this?

The behavior can be replicated here: https://sites.google.com/site/gchromeat/home/access

Comment: It seems a security measure, so I guess it's intended. If there is a way to go around it, it's probably a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you have used an Anchor object in your Google Apps Script. The reason why you get the redirect message is because the anchor object changes the link. 
Browsers detect the redirect and ask for user confirmation (browser settings can be changed to avoid this).

Also see [issue 1376](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1376) - which has been opened for getting rid of some undesirable side effects of this.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to go around this, as it seems to be a designed behavior. But there's an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1405) opened regarding this, you should star it to keep track of updates and kind of vote for it.